# Customize channel name for ibmcom/mq docker image

Tags: docker, ibm-mq

When i run the docker image ibmcom/mq:latest, I have DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN as a channel and QM1 queue manager.
I find the documentation to customize the queue manager but not the channel.

Could please help!!

Comment: Can you elaborate please what you mean by "customize the channel"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you looking to change the `DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN` channel name ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the default channel name DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN or add another channel and add the new queues will be associated the new channel.

Comment: @vs97 I want to create queues for my application using ibmmq image in docker. The idea is that queues created with the docker image have the same caracteristic as dev environnement. So i need to change the queue manager name and channel name.